Solving a Two-by-Two System of Trigonometric Equations
How do I solve the following 2-by-2 system of trigonometric equations where $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, and $y_2$ are known but $r$ and $\theta$ are unknown?
$$
    r = x_1 \cos\theta + y_1 \sin\theta\\
    r = x_2 \cos\theta + y_2 \sin\theta
$$

Hints:
Step 1, subtract the two equation. You get a single equation that contain $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. Step 2, move $\sin\theta$ term to one side, $\cos\theta$ term to the other side. Check if $\cos\theta=0$ is a solution, otherwise you can divide both sides by $\cos\theta$. You will get an equation of the type $$\tan\theta=\alpha$$
Can you take it from here?

Yes - thank you!

@Andrei One can explain it in a more general setting : $x \cos \theta+y \sin \theta = r$ is called the Euler form of the equation of a line, where $r$ is its (shortest) distance from the origin to the straight line and $\theta$ the polar angle of any vector normal to the line. Therefore, the idea is, being given these 2 points, to get a usual cartesian equation $ax+by=c$, then convert it to Euler form by dividing by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
